# Infinite scrolling in html

Tags: javascript

I am working on a java spring project and i have a table, made out of 5 pages.
I need to create a infinite scrolling using for a using html javascript css and call the method in a controller. I am pretty new to the programming world. Can you give me some tips or a good tuttorial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do Infinite Scrolling with just html and javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071164/how-do-i-do-infinite-scrolling-with-just-html-and-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you a generic answer, as you don't says which frameworks/library/languages you will use.

You have to search and learn how to do **lazy loading**. First a page is loaded with some content. A script (javascrip) in this page will check if the user is scrolling to the page bottom, and before it reach the bottom, the script will ask the next page and add it to current dom.

You can found lot of scripts and examples on the web, if you plan to use jQuery, you can start [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/) or [here](http://jscroll.com/).

Comment: I am working on a java spring project. I have a 5 pages table and i need a infinit scroll, wenn i reach the bottom of the first page the second page must load and so on.

Comment: Java is back end, the infinite scrolling is managed by the front-end. So read my answer in order to understand what you have to do.